# How to find the longest non divisible subset?

Tags: c, logic

```
    int nonDivisibleSubset(int k, int s_count, int* s) {
    int i,j;
    int count;
    int maxcount=0;
    for (i=0;i<s_count;i++)
    {   count=0;
        for (j=0;j<s_count;j++)
        {
            if (i=j)
            continue;
            else
            {
                if ((s[i]+s[j])%k==0)
                    continue;
                else 
                count=count+1;
            }

        }
    if (count>maxcount)
    {
        maxcount=count;
    }
    }
    return maxcount;
}
```

k is the number for which I am making the non divisible subset of subset 's'. I want to find the number of elements in longest subset

Comment: What does the shown code have to do with your question? Does it achieve the goal? Does it not? How not? What kind of help do you need? If it has a problem, then please turn it in to an [mre] which demonstrates that problem, including sample input with which the problem is visible.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by finding the longest non divisible subset (from the title) but from a single number as in the body "k is the number for which I am making the non divisible subset". Please elaborate. Since this is probably a homework assignment, how about quoting that as background? In full, verbatim and as text directly here, please.

Comment: If you need to explain more than one of your single-letter identifiers to help with understanding, then consider using meangingful variable-names instead.

Comment: https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/non-divisible-subset/problem this is the problem I was trying to solve, I realized my code is wrong, as it is not doing what I want it to do. can someone solve this ?

Comment: Can you pleae explain? What makes you think that your code is wrong? What does it do instead of what you want it to do? What do you want it do? With what input? Please make a MRE. (Not that question can be closed simply for asking "Why does this code not work?" without providing an MRE. And closing means, the system will not even allow people to answer, it - even if people would try to...)